# c pointer assignment to pointer to pointer what does it mean

Tags: c, pointers

I have a code snippet am struggling to understand.

```
char *c;   // c is uni dimensional table ( single row )

char **p ; // p is a two dimensional table 

**p = *c;  // what does this mean ?
```

When I do the above the assignment, is the c copied as first row of p ?

or c is copied as first column of p ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> **p = *c; // what does this mean ?
>
> When I do the above the assignment , Is the c copied as first row of p ? or c is copied as first column of p ?

Neither, that code is copying the first element of `c` to the first element of `p`. Is equivalent to

```
p[0][0] = c[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
char *c;   // c is uni dimensional table ( single row )
```

No, `c` is a pointer, not an array.  If you initialize it properly, it can point to the first element of an array, but the pointer itself is not an array.

```
char **p ; // p is a two dimensional table
```

No, `p` is a pointer to a `char*`; it's not a table.  Again, it might point to something that acts like a two-dimensional array.  A true two-dimensional array is simply an array of arrays, but there are several other ways to use pointers to simulate more flexible versions of 2-d arrays, with dynamic allocation and varying row sizes.

```
**p = *c;  // what does this mean ?
```

If `p` and `c` haven't been initialized, it means undefined behavior (which means your program crashes *if you're lucky*.  If they have been initialized properly: `p` points to a `char*` object; let's call that object `pstar`.  `pstar` points to a `char` object; let's call that object `pstarstar`.  `c` also points to a `char` object; let's call it `cstar`.  The assignment copies the value of `cstar` into `pstarstar`.

What that *means* depends on what `p` and `c` point to.

Recommended reading: section 6 of the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://c-faq.com).

Answer (score 0):

It means that the `char` that `c` points to is copied to whatever `p` points to points to.

```
c->some char
```

is copied to

```
p->*p->some char
```